# Is there any hardware to use in GPR applications?

Tags: rf-electronics, circuit-design

I want to make a radar system which needs to send EM wave and receive the reflected wave from the ground.

I am looking for a ready to use RF signal processing hardware but can't be sure which is applicable.

As I found that, the required frequency range for us is approx. 700 - 1000 MHz. So, we need to process this frequency of signal. I talk to somebody who told be that we need ADC having double the frequency we use which is 2GHz or something. I am not sure what we need else and what should be looked for.

I need to visualize beneath the ground with spatial image created from the signal read.

I searched for articles but couldn't find sufficient data about the hardware that we can use.

I suppose it is ok to have some ready to use evaluation boards from IC companies if they fit. Such as [this](http://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters/high-speed-ad-10msps/ad9625.html#product-evaluationkit).

Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad topic.  You are asking how to build a ground penetrating radar system from scratch. That is too big of a topic for one short question.

Comment: I know that actually I skimmed several websites like hackday.io or talked to a Ph.D. student and a Prof. in my university. They explained a few things but tow of them had some conflictions. For that reason, I confused a bit. I hope there may be some ready to use PCBs to work with by just designing an antenna and a software to program MCU or FPGA to command the transmitting signal and processing receiving one. If not, I am sure that there must be schematics of some sort of radar systems for SAR applications which I can't be sure if I am looking to the correct ones.

Comment: Prof. said that you need high-speed ADC so that you don't need to downconvert the signal to baseband in which technique keeping the phase data is note trivial. And a signal generator for transmitting part.
I am not sure what else I need for the circuit. I installed AWR software to play around and find some radar applications.
I found some applications where they just consider finding of velocity and a position of a target relative to the radar. But, what I need is to make some images out of radar reading. There are articles and algorithms but can't find hardware specs to accomplish this.